# How to return application/octet-stream in REST Spring?

Tags: spring, rest, mime-types

What is the best way to return `application/octet-stream` from `InputStream` from in `RestController`?
Do I have to write it to `HttpResponse` in "standard" Java way or does Spring provide some mechanism for this?

Comment: yes spring provide same mechanism..you need to wirte input streame in servlet output stream

Answer (score 0):

You can write your inputstream into spring fileInputStream

Just refer this example:

```
    File file = new File("File path");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", "get content type from file");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileCopyUtils.copy(fileInputStream, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: But this will send the http response only after the whole file has been read, right?

Comment: what you want to display exactly with octate stream

Comment: I am supposed to use it for sending the file content (even though I cannot say I am 100% convinced it is the best solution).

Comment: @LeNoob before doing this i did lots of R&D on sending file content. This is best solution i got.

Comment: But try sending a 3GB file using this. You will need 3 GB buffer for the file content right?

Comment: @LeNoob Yes that's the problem in this scenario.

Comment: @dev-null I remind one thing on this. You can flush buffer once you write content in response. I tried this thing.